# How should I automatically increase cordova app version and android version code on Microsoft Visual Studio Team Service build

Tags: cordova, azure-devops

I have created a build on Microsoft Visual Studio Team Service for my cordova app, and use it as Continues Integration and then creating a release and publishing release to Play Store, my only issue is I have to update app version and build number before check-in changes, Is there any way to update build number automatically and specially android version.

p.s I found this hook https://github.com/cnring18/cordova-build-increment it works on local and on server but when it changes the config.xml file on server there is no way to reflect the changes in source control (so it's temporary and it will increase once)

Comment: Do you solve this issue with my solution?

Comment: @starain Sorry not yet, First I am going to check the john solution on weekend, if it doesn't work I will get back to yours (It seems that one is working better for my issue) btw I up.vote yours too

Comment: What's the result after you trying john's solution?

Comment: @starain it's working ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this for at least two personal projects I've worked on. My approach was to use `gulp` and have a task which accepts a build # as a param and updates both `ios-CFBundleVersion` and `android-versionCode`. As part of my Build Definition in Team Services I include a `gulp` step which passes in the `$(Build.BuildNumber)`. For my projects, the `version` is set by the developer and under version control, while the build # is set by the build server.

**gulpfile**

https://gist.github.com/johnborges/56594765ef97c398269e59835ca23c5f

**Team Services Gulp Step**

*Command:* gulp

*Arguments:* bump-build --set-build-version $(Build.BuildNumber)

Comment: Interesting approach let me check the solution, and by this way I don't need to get the changes back to source control, right?

Comment: For solution I chose to not put the build #'s on source control. I'm sure there is a way to do that though.

Comment: No, I meant by this way we don't need to keep build number on our source control, because it will generated on build machine regardless of the current value, right? (and it's good to be like that)

Comment: Correct. It uses whatever Build # Scheme the build server follows. Which is usually customizable.

Answer (score 1):

> but when it changes the config.xml file on server there is no way to reflect the changes in source control

You can check-in/push changes to server via [TF](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/checkin-command)/[Git](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) command line (Commit first).

1. Add system environment variable for TF/Git tool if there isn't
   existing. (e.g. Variable:**TF_Home**, Value:**C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE**; Path: append **%TF_Home%;** value
2. Add Command Line step to your build/release definition.
3. Restart build agent machine.

[image]

You don't need to add environment variable if you are using Hosted Build agent, using it directly.

1. Check Allow Scripts to Access OAuth token option
   [image]
2. Command will be like this:
   [image]

Comment: thanks for answer, since I am working on VS Team Service (which is on Microsoft cloud) I don't have access to Environment Variables

Comment: @RezaRahmati You don't need to add environment variable to Hosted Build Agent, I updated my answer, you can check it.